# Instagram Graph API to views by region metrics

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Instagram Graph API to GET Instagram metrics. But not able to find any metrics called views by region of Instagram videos. Actually I'm trying to find total views for each reason not not able to find any Returnable Fields. Is there any metrics i.e, view_by_region or location_based_views_count or ?

**Please Let me know if the question is not clear enough.**

Answer (score 1):

Prophet. unfortunately there are no filters to use with the API to get views by region on Instagram.

Here is the exhaustive list of Insights metrics you can get for a **Media** Object:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights#insights-2

Here is the exhaustive list of Insights metrics you can get for a **User** Object:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights#insights-2

Note on a user object, it aggregates a metric across all your content in a given range.

Also note, that while you can get lifetime metrics for a followers audience geography using the **User** object on the Insights endpoint. You can retrieve Country, City, & Locale.

/GET {ig-user-id}/insights?metric=audience_locale&period=lifetime

Comment: Hi, you accidently pasted the same link twice. For the second one the link should be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights#insights-2

Answer (score 1):

There’s no filter like that available in graph Api.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).